# Why don't actions count towards quest?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-arena

The quests on my home screen are - play 25 lands, cast 20 red or green spells, cast 30 black or green spells.  I've been playing against Sparky with the green deck, but none of the quests have progressed.  How am I supposed to be doing these?

Comment: Sparky is the practice AI. Have you tried taking these actions in games against other players?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not complete quests VS AI you have to challenge other players in any other play mode for the actions to count toward quests.

Comment: I didn't even notice that after you click the "Play" button there are different options.  This apparently defaults to Practice, so you need to select the option "Play" (not the button) for the quests to progress.

Comment: Note that if you hover over a quest it will show you the allowed game modes, and once you press play to open the game mode menu any quests that don't progress in that mode will have a warning (for example if you select "Bot Match", your daily and weekly win quests will be replaced with the "Play PVP" warning).